# The pullback isn't the pushout by contradiction.

Tags: category-theory

The pullback $X \times_{Z} Y$ is the limit to the diagram in a category of sets consisting of the following:

$f: X \rightarrow Z$

$g: Y \rightarrow Z$.

That is to say there is a function $h: X \times_{Z} Y \rightarrow X$ and unique functions $c_{i}$ from *any* other given cone $C_{i}$ to $X \times_{Z} Y$ so any function $x_{i}: C_{i} \rightarrow X$ is equal to the composition of functions $x_{i}= h \circ c_{i}$...

I'd like to show in the category of sets that the pullback is not the pushout of the diagram

$j: Z \rightarrow X, k: Z \rightarrow Y$

by starting out with a contradiction; if it was the pullback there would probably be a unique morphism from the pullback $X \times_{Z} Y$ to the disjoint union $X \sqcup_{Z} Y$ but I'm thinking that there is more than one map or there is not a map at all. What do I have left to do?

Comment: I meant to put the question about the category of sets, I don't know if I put the same thing or if I accidentally changed the pullback by not being specific enough... and I added the reference material for what I am reading.

Comment: The problem isn’t the category, the problem is you used the term product and $X\times Y$ where you meant pullback.

Comment: Should I be using $X \sqcup_{X \times Y}} Y$ in the contradiction?

Comment: I mean, if $X$ and $Y$ are countably infinite, and $Z=\{z\},$ a set with a single point, it could be $X\sqcup Y,$ but the functions $\to X$ and $\to Y$ are not identities when restricted to $X$ and $Y.$ So do you mean that it can’t be $X\sqcup Y$ with the condition that the composition $X\to X\sqcup Y\to X$ is the identity, where the left map is the standard inclusion, and the right map is the standard projection?

Comment: Yea I just was not sure how I was going to use inclusion and projection again when I learned about them in the 'context of morphisms' and I am just concentrating on sets again but I'll keep trying.

Comment: What happens if $X = \emptyset = Y = Z$?

Comment: I think it must mean from $\rightarrow: X \sqcup Y \rightarrow X |_{X \in X \sqcup Y}$...

Comment: Your "That is..." is woefully incomplete. Being the pullback means that there are functions, *plural*, $h_X\colon X\times_Z Y\to X$ and $h_Y\colon X\times_Z Y\to Y$ such that $f\circ h_X=g\circ h_Y$, and is universal with that property.

Comment: An object by itself is not a limit or a colimit. You cannot just say "Is the pullback not the pushout?" Because "the pushout" is not just an object. It's an object *together with certain morphisms*. Before you can ask if the pullback object is a pushout object, you have to specify the functions as well. An object may fail to be universal if you use the "wrong" functions. For example, in $\mathsf{Group}$, given groups $G$ and $H$ the product is the object $G\times H$, **together with the canonical projection maps** $\pi_G\colon G\times H\to G$ and $\pi_H\colon G\times H\to H$. (cont)

Comment: (cont) If you take $G\times H$, but you equip it with the wrong maps (e.g., the trivial maps $G\times H\to G$ and $G\times H\to H$) then it is longer the product. Asking if $X\times _Z Y$ is the pushout is a nonsense question until you specify functions $X\to  X\times _Z Y$ and $Y\to X\times_Z Y$ to go with the object. Until you do, the question is meaningless. It's like asking if a set is a group: you can't answer the question until we know what operation you might be talking about.

Comment: What's the trivial map please? As opposed to the meaning of canonical projection map you are trying to teach me about..

Comment: In the context of groups, as in that comment, the trivial map is the map sending everything to the identity.