# If a product of sets can also identify elements with a common preimage then why isn't it the pushout?

Tags: category-theory

Starting with the functions $f:Z \rightarrow X$ and $g:Z \rightarrow Y$ there is a pushout of that diagram that identifies elements of $X$ and $Y$ which have a common preimage.

Hypothetically speaking if $Z$ is a singleton, if $f,g$ are injective surjective functions and if the pushout were $X \times Y$ then the product would identify two elements with the same preimage of $f,g$. Based on this information, why isn't the product & it's associated functions the pushout?

Comment: There is no canonical map *into* the product. How does it "identify elements with the same preimage", exactly?

Comment: Because, the inclusion map of the sets would have been that canonical map along with  tuple that could be the image of the two elements in it that both have the same preimage. By being the image of both of them they would be identified. ^_^

Comment: What "inclusion map of the sets"? There is no defined inclusion map of $X$ into $X\times Y$; $X$ is not a subset of $X\times Y$. Your entire thing is premised on "if the pushout were $X\times Y$"... which essentially asserts "if we somehow had functions from $X$ and $Y$ into $X\times Y$ which did a bunch of things..." but *there are no such functions*.

Comment: A pushout isn't just an object. It's an object together with moprhisms. Before you can meaningfully ask if something is a pushout, you have to specify both the object **and** the functions. Right now, it's like asking whether $\{x,y,z\}$ is a group. The question is meaningless, because we have not specified a complete structure to even be able to make sense of the question. You need to **specify** functions $X\to X\times Y$ and $Y\to X\times Y$ before you can ask if it is the pushout.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin There are such functions: $Z$ is a assumed a singleton, $f$ and $g$ are assumed bijections, so $X$ and $Y$ are also singletons, as is consquetly $X\times Y$. In that case the pushout and the product coincide as I've indicated in my answer. Consider actually reading questions in the future instead of leaving rude and condescending comments.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov For specific cases, there might just happen to be such functions, but in general there is no canonical choice. This is neither "rude" nor "condescending", so in the future, consider that what you read into a comment need not be what is actually in that comment, rather than engage in ad hominems.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What I specifically find rude and condescending is you choosing to dismiss the specifics of the question and lecture on generalities instead, especially when those specifics actually address your objections. Imagine you asked a specific question and someone just lectured you on generalities you already understand and have already addressed.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov What I read, especially in conjunction with other similarly worded questions from OP is a general question, followed by a specific example (rather than simply a specific question) in an attempt to come to grips with the general question. I am addressing the generalities because, across several questions, the OP seems to be struggling with the general issue, and is only using a specific example in an attempt to come to those grips. Here, I think the specific example is actually misleading because the answer occurs by happenstance, with no connection with the problem in general.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: In short order, the OP asked: [why the pullback is not a pushout in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415888/742), and a [second question on pushouts and pullbacks](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4414993/742). In context, this is not a specific question in isolation, hence talking about the generalities (which, in context, does not appear to be something the OP "already understand[s] and ha[s] already addressed". Hence, again, what you read as "rude and condescending" turns out to be born from your perception, rather than the facts on the ground as I see them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin All the linked questions ask the same thing (or its dual): when does the (vertex of) a cartesian product (or pullback) fail to have the structure of a pushout of its factors and/or how to show that it does fail? I see this is the *second* time you decided to not answer the question and just lecture in the comments. Comments are for requesting clarifications and suggesting improvements. Next time the urge to lecture overwhelms you, leave an answer so I can downvote it.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: I asked a question, right in this post, right at the top. The answer was nonresponsive ("the inclusion map"... what inclusion map? it's not a subset). Perhaps you might want to take your own advice and not lecture where it is not appropriate.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin as I already tried to explain, the inclusion maps are the ones from the hypothesized identification of (the vertex of) the product with the coproduct. Even if you were not wrong (and you are wrong, most amusingly because $2+2=2\times2$) that such (canonical) maps cannot exist, it would have been more helpful if you actually explained, specifically, in an answer, why they couldn't. Your commenting strategy is evidently unhelpful (certainly didn't dissuade the OP from repeatedly posting the same question). Also, the correct response is to apologize for being rude, not double-down.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: Allow me to correct the record in one issue: "certainly didn't dissuade the OP from repeatedly posting the same question".  The questions posted were on: March 28, 22:56Z. On March 30, 00:56Z; and on March 30, 13:10Z. My earliest comment is on this post, on March 30, 13:14Z, after all three posts had been made. I do not see how any comment of mine, no matter how helpful or unhelpful, could have possibly prevented actions that had already taken place by the time I  made them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both finite sets, i.e. if $X\times Y$ is finite, then this is usually impossible for size reasons: size of the product $X\times Y$ is the product of the sizes of $X$ and $Y$ (the number of ordered pairs), while the size of the pushout of $Z\to X$ and $Z\to Y$ is at most the sum of the sizes of $X$ and $Y$ (for $Z\to X$ and $Z\to Y$ both injective, it's minus the size of $Z$). For details on these estimates, see the end of the answer.

In particular for finite sets and $Z\to X$ and $Z\to Y$ injective this is only possible if all sets are empty, if $Z$ and one of $X$ or $Y$ is a singleton, or if $Z$ is empty, and both $X$ and $Y$ have size $2$. Indeed, if $x,y,z$ stand for the sizes of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, then we would need $xy=x+y-z$. If $x$ is zero, then $z$ would have to be zero, and then $y$ would have to be zero. If $x$ is $1$, then $x$ and $z$ are equal. If $x$ and $y$ are both $2$, then $z$ is zero. Otherwise, if one of $x$ or $y$ is more than $2$, then $xy>x+y\geq x+y-z$.

---

The question at hand is a special case of when $Z$ and $X$ singletons. In that case, we have that the projection map $X\times Y\to Y$ is an isomorphism. Indeed, we have $\{*\}\times Y=\{(*,y):y\in Y\}$, for which the projection $\{*\}\times Y\to Y$ is evidently a bijection.

More abstractly,  singletons are terminal objects in the sense that for any set $W$ there is a unique function to any given singleton. Consequently, pairs of morphisms, one of which is to a terminal object, are the same information as a single morphism, so $Y$ equipped with the identity morphism $Y\to Y$ and the unique morphism $Y\to X$ is also product, and hence canonically isomorphic to $X\times Y$.

Now, the pushout of $f\colon Z\to X$ and $g\colon Z\to Y$ when $f$ is an isomorphism is quite simply $Y$ itself, with inclusion functions given by $g\circ f^{-1}\colon X\cong Z\to Y$ and $\mathrm{id}_Y\colon Y\to Y$. Set-theoretically, every element of $x$ is equivalent to a unique element of $y$, so every element of $Y$ is a representative of a unique equivalence class constiuting the pushout $X\sqcup_ZY$.

Thus, if $Z$ and $X$ are both terminal objects in a category, then we have canonical isomorphisms $X\times Y\cong Y\cong X\sqcup_ZY$ for any $Z\to Y$.

---

The remaining possibilities for identifying a pushout with a product in finite sets are for the cases where $Z$ is the empty set, i.e. initial object, so the identification of coproducts with products. These are slightly more involved from a categorical point of view.

The case where $X$ is empty, i.e. an initial object, the inclusion $Y\cong X\sqcup Y$ is an isomorphism (for reasons dual to the argument that the projection of a product with a terminal object is an isomorphism). Set-theoretically, the disjoint union of a set with the empty set is in bijection with the original set.

In the case of sets $X$ is also a strict initial object, meaning that any morphism to it is an isomorphism (the only functions to the empty set is the empty function). Thus $X\times Y$ having a projection to the strict initial object $X$ is an isomorphism, so $X\times Y$ is also an initial object. Set-theoretically, $\{(x,y):x\in X,y\in Y\}$ is empty when $X$ is empty.

---

Finally, for finite sets, we have the case where $X$ and $Y$ both have size $2$. This is actually the most interesting case. What's happening is that a set of size $2$ is the coproduct of singletons. Categorically, $\mathbf 2=\mathbf 1\sqcup\mathbf 1$ is the coproduct of terminal objects.

Now in general, $(A\times B)\sqcup(A\times C)$ has a unique morphism to $A\times(B\sqcup C)$ arising from the two morphisms $A\times B\to A\times(B\sqcup C)$ and $A\times C\to A\times(B\sqcup C)$. In particular, we have $\mathbf 2\sqcup\mathbf 2\cong(\mathbf 2\times\mathbf 1)\sqcup(\mathbf 2\times\mathbf 1)\to\mathbf 2\times(\mathbf 1\sqcup\mathbf 1)\cong\mathbf 2\times\mathbf 2$.

In the case of sets, this natural map is a bijection (more generally, categories are distributive if always $(A\times B)\sqcup(A\times C)\cong A\times(B\sqcup C)$). Explicitly, if $\mathbf 2=\{0,1\}$, then $\{0,1\}\sqcup\{0,1\}\cong\{(0,0),(1,0)\}\sqcup\{(0,1),(1,1)\}=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}\cong\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$. What is interesting here is that the one projection of the product selects the element of one of the original $\mathbf 2$'s, while the second projection selects which of the two $\mathbf 2$'s that element was in. The reason this is intersting, is that it can be categorically abstracted to the notion of a boolean object: $\mathbf 2$ is a coproduct of two terminal objects so that the above morphism is an isomorphism. Such objects play a key role in the category-theoretic instantiaton of the notion of boolean algberas.

---

To finish the story for sets, if $X\times Y$ is an infinite set, then it has the same cardinality as $X\sqcup_ZY$, so the two always have a bijection between them, hence $X\times Y$ can always be equipped with the structure of a pushout. However, this structure will not be compatible with the product structure in any meaningful way. As an example, we have a bijection of the set of pairs of natural numbers with the set of natural numbers, and a bijection of the set of natural numbers with the disjoint union with itself via bijections to the sets of even and odd natural numbers.

---

Let $X\times Y$ stand for the product. More precisely, this means we have morphisms $\pi_1\colon X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_2\colon X\times Y\to Y$ such that for every pair of morphisms $h_1\colon W\to X$ and $h_2\colon W\to Y$, there is a unique morphism $h\colon W\to X\times Y$ (sometimes written using order pair notation $h=(h_1,h_2)\colon W\to X\times Y$) such that $\pi_1\circ h=h_1$ and $\pi_2\circ h=h_2$.

In set theory, the product is usually the set $X\times Y=\{(x,y):x\in X,y\in Y\}$ of ordered pairs of elements of $X$ and $Y$ (for some notion of ordered pair, e.g. Kuratowski's $(x,y)=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$), and the projection functions are the set-theoretic functions $\pi_1\colon (x,y)\mapsto x$ and $\pi_2\colon(x,y)\mapsto y$. Let me leave it as an exercise to check that these satisfy the defining universal property defined above. Note that for finite sets, the size of the product is the umber of ordered pairs, so the product of the sizes.

---

Let $X\sqcup_ZY$ stand fo the pushout of $f\colon Z\to X$ and $g\colon Z\to Y$. This means more precisely that we have morphism $i_1\colon X\to X\sqcup_ZY$ and $i_2\colon Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ such that for any pair of morphisms $h_1\colon X\to W$ and $h_2\colon Y\to W$ that satisfy $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ g$, there exists a unique morphism $h\colon X\sqcup_Z Y\to W$ such that $h\circ i_1=h_1$ and $h\circ i_2=h_2$.

In set theory, the pushout is usually presented in two stages.

First, when $Z$ is the empty set, there is for every other set $W$ a unique empty function $Z\to W$ (i.e. $Z$ is an initial object). In particular, $f\colon Z\to X$ and $g\colon Z\to Y$ are both the empty function, and moreover any pair of morphisms $h_1\colon X\to W$ and $h_2\colon Y\to W$ satisfy $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ g$.

Consequently, the universal property defining $X\sqcup_ZY$ reduces to the one defining the coproduct $X\sqcup Y$ when $Z$ is an initial object. Namely, there is a pair of morphisms $i_1\colon X\to X\sqcup Y$ and $i_2\colon Y\to X\sqcup Y$ such that for any pair of morphisms $h_1\colon X\to W$ and $h_2\colon Y\to W$, there exists a unique morphism $h\colon X\sqcup_Z Y\to W$ such that $h\circ i_1=h_1$ and $h\circ i_2=h_2$.

In set theory, the coproduct $X\sqcup Y$ is the disjoint union of the two sets. One explicit construction is $X\sqcup Y=\{(0,x):x\in X\}\cup\{(1,y):y\in Y\}$, with functions $i_1\colon x\mapsto(0,x)$ and $i_2\colon y\mapsto(1,y)$.

The second stage is the realization that the inclusion morphism $X\to X\sqcup_ZY$ and $Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ imply there is a unique morphism $e\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ from the coproduct such that $e\circ i_1\colon X\to X\sqcup_ZY$ and $e\circ i_2\colon Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ are the inclusions of the pushout.

It turns out that $e\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ also satisfies a universal property. Namely, pairs of morphisms $h_1\colon X\to W$ and $h_2\colon Y\to W$ that satisfy $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ g$ correspond to morphisms $k\colon X\sqcup_Y\to W$ such that $k\circ i_1\circ f=k\circ i_2\circ g$ and $k\circ i_1=h_1$, $k\circ i_2=h_2$. Consequently, $e\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ has the universal property that for any $k\colon X\sqcup Y\to W$ such that $k\circ i_1\circ f=h\circ i_2\circ g$ there is a unique morphism $h\colon X\sqcup_YZ\to W$ such that $h\circ e=k$.

In other words, $e\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\sqcup_ZY$ is what is known as a coequalizer of $i_1\circ f\colon Z\to X\to X\sqcup Y$ and $i_2\circ g\colon Z\to Y\to X\sqcup Y$.

In the category of sets, coequalizers can be constructed as quotients of equivalence relations. Thus $X\sqcup_ZY$ consists of equivalence classes of elements of $X$ and $Y$ for the relation generated by $x\sim y$ if there exists $z\in f^{-1}(x)\cap g^{-1}(y)\subseteq Z$. In particular, the size of the pushout $X\sqcup_ZY$ is the number of equivalence classes on $X\sqcup Y$ generated by that relation, so at most the size of $X\sqcup Y$, i.e. at most the sum of the sizes of $Z$ and $Y$.

Moreover, if $f\colon Z\to X$ and $g\colon Z\to Y$ are injective, then the only non-singleton equivalence classes consist of pairs of elements $x$ and $y$ of the form $f(z)$ and $g(z)$. Thus in that case the size of $X\sqcup_Z Y$ is the sum of the sizes of $X$ and $Y$ minus the size of $Z$.